# How to SSH into linux server over the internet

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I have looked everywhere, and I still am not getting the result I want.

when on the same local network, I can ssh into my linux ubuntu server using name@10.1.1.x
I can also ssh into it using my public ip.
I am port forwarding port 22 using TCP, with the ip set to the private ip of the server.
When I try to ssh to it via the internet, so not on the same local network, the connection always times out. At canyouseemee.org, the port does not appear to be open. I have no idea what I'm doing and I have seen many tutorials on stack exchange and elsewhere, and still I have no progress. I must be doing something wrong on the server, since I'm already port forwarding port 22. If there's any additional information needed lmk.

btw it might be helpful to know that I'm running a minecraft server on it, and that can forward port 25565 successfully.

further to that, I have an online webapp that opens a dashboard for the server, and that has a port as well. I can also forward that port, and it works successfully.
I honestly have no clue what is going on.. other ports except 22 are working.

here is the sshd config:

```
# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem sftp  /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
PasswordAuthentication yes
GatewayPorts yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

EDIT: Thanks to someone in the comments, they made it aware to me that my ISP might be blocking access to port 22. I changed the port in the ssh config file and it worked.

Comment: Do you have fail2ban or similar running, if so, check that they are blocking you. You could also be denying connections by entries in your sshd config file. Can you put that in your question?

Comment: It **might** be firewall settings from where you are trying to ssh when you're remote: I work in a hospital and can't ssh into my home computer from the hospital wifi but I can if I tether my laptop to my mobile and use exactly the same commands. You said you can access it using the public IP address when you're on the same network so that suggests it all works including the port forwarding - so it seems likely something at the other end when you're remote.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I added the ssh config file. I added Allow tcp forwarding and gateway ports myself. Still didn't work.

Comment: @Will I got a friend to do it, and he couldn't connect either, and I also tried using my mobile data and it didn't work.

Comment: Hello. I suppose you may need to ask your ISP to allow the incoming traffic on that port (or at all ports). Some ISPs blocks this port for some kind of security reason. Before asking them, you can try to use different port - I would suggest you 80 or 443, because thy are usually reserved for HTTP the ISPs allow incoming traffic on them in most cases.

Comment: @pa4080 I'll give it a shot cheers

Comment: @pa4080 dude it worked thanks a lot this took me ages

Comment: I'm happy to help, KevoK! I've converted the comment to an answer - you could accept it if you like :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you may need to ask your ISP to allow the incoming traffic on that port (or at all ports, or at any other port). Some ISPs block the incoming traffic on port 22 for security reasons.

Before asking the ISP anything, you can try to use a different port. I would suggest you to try with 80 or 443 first, because thy are usually reserved for HTTP traffic, and the ISPs allow incoming traffic on them in most cases.

Note, if this is the case, it is not mandatory to change anything on your SSH server, instead you can do a port forwarding like:

```
{public-ip}:80 > {lan-ip}:22
```